# How can you show the navigation arrows in Flex slider 2?

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I want to use Flex slider 2 but I can not display the navigation arrows with hover. I read a lot of other answers, but I'm still not able to fix the problem.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I do it on my site. I position them outside of their container (with an overflow: hidden on it) and bring them back into the container on hover. This can be done with any Flexslider version, as it is CSS, not Flexslider, that handles the effect.

http://www.magmadesigngroup.com/portfolio-portfolio/projects/woodland-cottage as an example